# How to merge and return new array from object in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Suppose there are two objects.

```
const a = [
  { id: '1-1-1', name: 'a111' },
  { id: '1-1-2', name: 'a112' },
  { id: '1-2-1', name: 'a121' },
  { id: '1-2-2', name: 'a122' },
  { id: '2-1-1', name: 'a211' },
  { id: '2-1-2', name: 'a212' }
]
const b = ['1-1', '1-2', '2-1']
```

and the result

```
  {

      '1-1':[
        { id: '1-1-1', name: 'a111' },
        { id: '1-1-2', name: 'a112' },
      ],
      '1-2':[
          { id: '1-2-1', name: 'a121' },
          { id: '1-2-2', name: 'a122' },
      ],
      '2-1':[
        { id: '2-1-1', name: 'a211' },
        { id: '2-1-2', name: 'a212' },
      ]
    }
```

Basically, I want to group the data.

I use `includes` to check if the item from `b` to match the id from `a`. Then construct the new array.

This is my attempt([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gvr0tkh/)):

```
return b.map(item => a.map(jtem => {
  if(jtem.id.includes(item)){
    return {
      [item]: jtem
    }
  }
}))
```

For somehow, it doesn't work.

and, is there a clever way to avoid the nested `for` loop or `map` function?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be an object?

Comment: @JackBashford Hey man, sry, u r right, I just updated it.

Comment: Do you really want `includes`? I'd recommend `startsWith`

Comment: @Bergi thx, I think `startWith` is better

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Apply `reduce()` on the array `b`
- During each iteration use `filter()` on the the array `a`
- Get all the items from `a` which starts with item of `b` using [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
- At last set it as property of the `ac` and return `ac`

```js
const a = [
  { id: '1-1-1', name: 'a111' },
  { id: '1-1-2', name: 'a112' },
  { id: '1-2-1', name: 'a121' },
  { id: '1-2-2', name: 'a122' },
  { id: '2-1-1', name: 'a211' },
  { id: '2-1-2', name: 'a212' }
]
const b = ['1-1', '1-2', '2-1']

let res = b.reduce((ac,b) => {
  
  ac[b] = a.filter(x => x.id.startsWith(b));
  return ac;

},{})
console.log(res)
```

As suggested by @Falco is the comments that It would be better to scan over the `a` once as its large. So here is that version.Actually its better regarding performance

```js
const a = [
  { id: '1-1-1', name: 'a111' },
  { id: '1-1-2', name: 'a112' },
  { id: '1-2-1', name: 'a121' },
  { id: '1-2-2', name: 'a122' },
  { id: '2-1-1', name: 'a211' },
  { id: '2-1-2', name: 'a212' }
]
const b = ['1-1', '1-2', '2-1']


let res = a.reduce((ac,x) => {
  let temp = b.find(y => x.id.startsWith(y))
  if(!ac[temp]) ac[temp] = [];
  ac[temp].push(x);
  return ac;
},{})

console.log(res)
```

**Note**: `startsWith` is not supported by I.E. So you can create polyfill using `indexOf`

```js
if(!String.prototype.startWith){
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return this.indexOf(str) === 0
  }
}
```

Comment: While it is specifically said in the question that the op wants to use es6, and that IE don't support es6 features, I just want to mention that startsWith() don't work in IE (while reduce, filter, and setting a property of an object is totally fine if IE > 9) and if someone wants to do the same thing that startsWith do, they can implment their own with some substring :)

Comment: For big `a` and small `b` I would probably go with `a.reduce(...)` because of locality and only scan over the big array once.

Comment: @MaheerAli Thank you - here is a benchmark comparing the two :-) https://jsbench.me/dfjtoadysr/1